# Calling an async method without awaiting

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to call an async method (in an ASP.NET Web API 2 app) without awaiting for the result. I mean I want to main thread to continue executing and no-wait for called method to get completed. I'm trying this snippet:

```
// The async method:
private static async Task LogAsync(Exception exception, string ip, MethodBase method, object parameters) {
    // some stuff 
}

// The caller methods:
public static void Log1(Exception exception, object parameters) {
    LogAsync(exception, ip, method, parameters);
}
public static void Log2(Exception exception, object parameters) {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LogAsync(exception, ip, method, parameters));
}
public static async void Log3(Exception exception, object parameters) {
    await LogAsync(exception, ip, method, parameters).ConfigureAwait(true);
}
public static async void Log4(Exception exception, object parameters) {
    // I've tried even this one:
    await LogAsync(exception, ip, method, parameters).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

As you can see, I tried different ways; but non of them give me what I want. Do you have any idea, what would help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'm trying to call an async method (in an ASP.NET Web API 2 app) without awaiting for the result.

Are you sure that's what you want to do? On ASP.NET, if you start up independent work like this (that is, work *not related to an HTTP request*), then that work may be aborted without your knowledge. In this scenario, your methods are called "log", so presumably they are logging asynchronously. So you only want to *avoid* the `await` if it's perfectly acceptable to occasionally lose logs. If you want your logs to be reliable, you'll need to keep the `await`. Your call.

Assuming that it's OK to occasionally lose logs, then you should at least register the work with the ASP.NET runtime. If you're on .NET 4.5.2, you can use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`, as such:

```
public static void Log(Exception exception, object parameters) {
  HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(_ =>
      LogAsync(exception, ip, method, parameters));
}
```

If you're on an older version of .NET (4.5 or 4.5.1), you can use my [AspNetBackgroundTasks library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks):

```
public static void Log(Exception exception, object parameters) {
  BackgroundTaskManager.Run(() =>
      LogAsync(exception, ip, method, parameters));
}
```

The semantics between the two are slightly different (I have a writeup [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)), but they both register the work with the ASP.NET runtime so at least it's not *entirely* unreliable like `Task.Factory.StartNew` or `Task.Run` is.

Answer (score 0):

You've got it right.

The first method is what you need.

```
// The caller methods:
public static void Log1(Exception exception, object parameters) {
    LogAsync(exception, ip, method, parameters);
}
```

The problem may be somewhere else. How do you test this?

Log1's `LogAsync` will be executed on a different thread. It's like fire and forget which is exactly what you need.

EDIT:
Try changing the LogAsync method to:

```
// The async method:

        private static void LogAsync(Exception exception, string ip, MethodBase method, object parameters) {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate {
            // some stuff });
        }
```

Comment: I added somt Debug.Write(message) to trace. Also, I put a thread.sleep(seconds) on the async method. The request won't complete until the async method get completed.

Comment: I've changed the caller to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` and it works ;) you can change your suggestion and I'll accept the answer. But, does this has any performance side effects? See here please: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29578284/645167

Comment: I had just made the edit before your reply :). The problem lies in WebAPI and how it handles the await stuff. Check out the SyncronizationContext that is used in asp.net and webapi. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx

Comment: However to avoid creating/pooliong threads for every log message what I'll do is to spin up a thread that is constantly monitoring a Queue for messages then insert message to that queue in the current context and leave the "logging" thread to persist it (may be in the db)

Comment: Good idea. Actually I had thought about before. May be I use that

Comment: May be a static ConcurrentQueue see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx will do the trick. The idea is that you create a thread start a while(true) loop in that loop you constantly try to dequeue and check the queue size if the size is 0 you can Sleep the tread for example 100ms. The in the web api controllers you Enqueue log messages. This is the simplest thing I can come up with, you may be better off using a dedicated queueing system like MSMQ, RabbitMQ, DotNetMQ etc :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75005/discussion-between-mcl-and-javad-amiry).

Comment: Erm, if you change the method to not be `async`, its name needs to change also.