# Is "await" keyword compulsory with async methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have following methods:

```
async Task A()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");        
}

async Task B()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://google.com");
}
```

i.e calling remote api, process on the response, and return nothing.

I will be calling it like this from a common method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    A();
    B();

    // Do further task after this which is not dependent on response of A or B
}
```

The compiler gives me following warning on A and B methods:

> Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method
>   continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await'
>   operator to the result of the call.

[image]

I don't need any response back from A or B methods so I am thinking to omit "await" keyword in front of A() and B() since I want to execute the code after A and B call where I have written comment "// Do further task after this which is not dependent on response of A or B" without waiting for A or B response.

Can I ignore compiler warning?

Am I misusing the API?

I can't remove the async operator over A and B methods since HttpClient.GetStringAsync demands for it.

**Edit**:

I went to this link 
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331353/does-omitting-await-keyword-once-in-the-call-stack-break-the-asynchronous-behavi

and found the following comment:

"When you do not await an async method it is equivalent to calling Task.Run(()=>A())."

**Is this true**?

Comment: `await Task.Run(()=>{A();B();});`

Comment: What are you doing with the `response` object ? If the code after calling `A` and `B` doesn't need `A` and `B` to be done, then your way is fine.

Comment: Why "await" is necessary in your line? I don't want any response back from those two methods.

Comment: If fire and forget is what you want, you can safely ignore the warning in most contexts (except for instance ASP.NET). Some libraries, like Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, even provide helpers to suppress those warnings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.tplextensions.forget.aspx

Comment: There are plenty of "c# fire-and-forget" questions already... Please make sure to [edit] post to demonstrate results of your research - otherwise people may think you didn't even try and downvote the question.

Comment: "If fire and forget is what you want": I just want to be sure from those two methods that they will complete and don't get lost while calling it without await.

Comment: @Raghav That's "fire and forget". It's perfectly safe. The only notable exception is ASP.NET, where IIS can't track the additional tasks, and could think the worker process isn't doing anything and recycle it

Comment: @Raghav So your question is, How do I ensure that a Task that is not awaited run to completion in ASP.NET ? .. .Right ?

Comment: Yes, that was my other concern apart from warning which compiler is giving me. So yes my queries were "Should I ignore the warning", Will my code do complete if I ignore await keyword while calling a method having async on it.

Comment: Re: your edit - read the bottom comment on that answer where it's already pointed out that it's *not* equivalent to `Task.Run(()=>A());`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `await` ensures that `Task` completes it's execution. Running `async` method without `await` is like just starting `Task` without monitoring it's progress and results.

For example, in ASP.Net environment that can result in tasks being aborted if they started from request thread etc.

Comment: "Running async method without await is like just starting Task without monitoring it's progress and results"

I have no issue with that i.e without monitoring its progress and results but does that guaranty that the code will execute or will break/lost in between if I don't apply that await keyword while calling it.

Comment: @Raghav - if you don't care about their progress or results, you may as well replace the method bodies with empty ones, or remove the method calls entirely.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I do care about the completion of the code I am writing inside A and B, although I don't care about what these methods return. Since I am calling it from ASP.NET page load I have to apply await in front of A and B for its completion guarantee and omitting await can lead to abort those methods (without await keyword), Right?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: [Fire and Forget in ASP.NET](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)

In your code, the **Do further task after this which is not dependent on response of A or B** part executes before the methods `A` and `B` are done (unless these are very fast).

When you use `await` and the method hits that line it returns a `Task` to the caller and the caller continue the executes of the second line (`B` in your case), since `B` does the same, then the part after calling these two method executes.

**Side-Note:**

Each method that uses the `await` keyword should be marked as async, this is for backward comparability. However, the compiler is just warning you that you're not awaiting the result in the caller, and this is a good warning in many cases for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

If fire and forget is what you want, you can safely ignore the warning in most contexts (except for instance ASP.NET). Some libraries, like Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, even provide helpers to suppress those warnings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.tplextensions.forget.aspx

You can use it this way:

```
// Forget doesn't actually do anything internally. 
// It's an empty extension method you use to prove that you actually want the task to be
// fire and forget
A().Forget();
B().Forget();
```

You can also have some weird behaviors if you're executing in a synchronization context and the method internally does a `await` without `ConfigureAwait(false)`. That's one of the reasons `.ConfigureAwait(false)` should always be used in library code.

---

For the second part of your question:

> "When you do not await an async method it is equivalent to calling Task.Run(()=>A())."
>
> Is this true?

**It's wrong.** There's at least two major differences:

1. When using an `async` method, the part preceding the first `await` will execute synchronously in the caller thread. For instance:

   ```
   public async Task DoSomething()
   {
       Thread.Sleep(1000); // Will execute in the caller thread
       await SomeExternalResource();
       Thread.Sleep(1000); // Will execute in the continuation
   }
   ```

   Here, if you call directly the method, the caller thread will be blocked during at least 1 second (at least, because there's a possibility the continuation will execute in the same thread). If you use `Task.Run`, the whole method will be executed on the threadpool, and won't block the caller thread.
2. Using `Task.Run` executes the method without flowing the current synchronization context, which can change significantly the behavior in some cases

Comment: @Itsik I fail to see how `.ConfigureAwait(false)` could cause a deadlock. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Using ConfigureAwait on the outer call will do nothing to nested inner awaits

Comment: @KevinGosse sorry you are right, not a deadlock , the opposite! But in client-code he will have the issue that he may not be able to update the UI since the synchronization context has changed

Comment: Thanks @KevinGosse for replying on my edit.

Comment: "You can also have some weird behaviors if you're executing in a synchronization context and the method internally does a await without ConfigureAwait(false)"

Yes , one of them is a deadlock which can be when calling the async mthood from UI synchronization context.

Comment: @KevinGosse In nutshell, I CAN use the async methods without await keywords while calling them and that async method will DO complete, Right?

Comment: @Raghav Yup, that's correct

Comment: @KevinGosse I was reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577652/calling-an-async-method-without-awaiting and found this reply from Stephan "On ASP.NET, if you start up independent work like this (that is, work not related to an HTTP request), then that work may be aborted without your knowledge." That comment has once again left me in dilemma whether A or B methods will do complete.

Comment: @Raghav ASP.NET is really the one exception. And it is not a problem about "not awaiting a task", but rather fire-and-forget in general

Comment: @KevinGosse that means I have to apply await for its completion guarantee since I am calling them from Pageload event of my ASP.NET page. So omiting await can lead to abort those methods (without await keyword), Right? Probably this will be my last query on this thread :)

Comment: @KevinGosse is that correct, I am stuck at my last comment with ASP.NET context.

Comment: @Raghav Yes, in WebForm you should await them (don't forget to also set `aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` to true in the configuration: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for providing *Yes, in WebForm you should await them* reply.

Answer (score 0):

If the execution of A and B are asynchronous to the rest of the flow of Page_Load you don't have to `await` them.

Another option than ones given here is to show that you are ignoring this warning explicitly to someone else that reads your code, is to wrap it with #pragma disable

```
#pragma warning disable warning-list  

A();
B();

#pragma warning restore warning-list
```