# Guaranteeing the code to complete in separate thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have written the following code to execute a method in a different thread to offload a new work to new thread so that my primary thread can process the rest of the work fast and can complete the web page request.

```
public static Task ExecuteAsynchronously(Action action)
{
    HttpContext currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(()
        =>
    {
        HttpContext.Current = currentContext;
        // Execute the desired action
        action();
    });
    return task;
}
```

I will be calling that method from ASP.NET Web UI context from the page load event of a page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MethodA()

    Utility.ExecuteAsynchronously(() =>
    {
        // Do a long running task in separate thread
        MethodC()
    });

    MethodB()
}
```

i.e

I have the following questions on the above code:

1. Is it guaranteed that the code "Do a long running task in separate thread" will complete or it can abort if the page load event
   finishes before with work done in `MethodA` and `MethodB` methods?
2. Can we even use `Task.Factory.StartNew` in `ASP.NET` context and
   guarantees that our work assigned in separate task will DO complete?
3. How can we be sure to take the heavy/long operation load(in some
   method) away from `ASP.NET` primarily thread which is serving the
   request and be dead sure that code in separate thread will complete
   and is not aborted in between when the request of `ASP.NET` page is
   completed before? Is this even possible?
4. Can we use `async-await` to over come that issue?

Edit: Please note I am not talking about the background tasks which can run at regular intervals.

Comment: Scott Hanselman put together a useful blog post on [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.Net](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Comment: If you read the post I've linked to, you'll realise that some of the solutions are applicable no matter what the *nature* of the background task is. You'll also realise that you're focussing on the *wrong* risks (e.g. the biggest single risk to randomly created tasks or threads is that ASP.Net has no real knowledge of them and so can feel free to *recycle the application pool* which will kill a simple task)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I didn't mean to offend you with my edit. "ASP.Net has no real knowledge of them and so can feel free to recycle the application pool which will kill a simple task" apart from recycle can my task be killed if my request is completed before that?

Comment: No, precisely the opposite. The *risk*, as I said above, is that asp.net has no knowledge of this task. More precisely, there is *nothing* linking that task to the original request.

Comment: Okay, so you mean to say that since there is no knowledge with new Task about the current request it can complete on its own and will not die even if the original ASP.NET request is completed.

Comment: Do you not have a need for the result of your _long running task_? As written the code will never receive a result.

Comment: I don't need the result back I just want the code to complete for sure.

Comment: Just a FYI, not a issue with ASP.NET but using `StartNew` without passing in `TaskSchedueller.Default` could cause your code to run on the UI thread in some conditions. See [StartNew is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Comment: Even if you're not running background tasks a regular intervals, that link by Scott Hanselman has plenty of valid solutions applicable to your situation. Read it over carefully.

Comment: @Raghav Scott Hanselman's article explains how to run a long running job in an ASP.NET application *correctly*. At the very least you *have* to use `QueueBackgroundWorkItem`. Calling it is actually a lot easier than what you are trying to do. The other methods are better, but you can consider this a ready-made implementation of what you are trying to do with `ExecuteAsynchronously`.

Comment: @Raghav just replace your `Utility.ExecuteAsynchronously(()=>...` with `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct=>...`

Answer (score 1):

> Is it guaranteed that the code `Do a long running task in separate thread` will complete or it can abort if the page load event finishes before with work done in `MethodA` and `MethodB` methods?

No, it's not guaranteed at all. Moreover, this task' thread will probably reused for handling some other responses, without any notification for you.

> Can we even use `Task.Factory.StartNew` in ASP.NET context and guarantees that our work assigned in separate task will DO complete?

As already been said, none of these is guaranteed. Moreover, `StartNew` is internal method that should not be used, `Task.Run` is much preferable yet not helpful in this situation.

> How can we be sure to take the heavy/long operation load (in some method) away from ASP.NET primarily thread which is serving the request and be dead sure that code in separate thread will complete and is not aborted in between when the request of ASP.NET page is completed before? Is this even possible?

As already been said in comments, you *should* use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` method to such work, if you do not need the result of the background task.

> Can we use async-wait to over come that issue?

**`ASP.NET` is already async**, by definition. There is no need to get another thread to execute an action if you need the result - just run the code in current thread.

---

Now, back to your **real** problem. What you're trying to do is passing the `HttpContext.Current` to the background task, **which is not recommended thing to do**. From [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-background-processes-in-asp-net/):

> The caller’s [`ExecutionContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.executioncontext.aspx) is not flowed to the work item. For example, the code that you run in the background thread doesn’t have access to commonly used context properties. **If you need [`HttpContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) information, copy the values you care about to a state object or inside a closure and pass it in to the background worker.**
>
> Don’t pass the [`HttpContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) instance itself, **as it’s not a thread-safe object** and even simple property getters (like [`HttpContext.Request.Url`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.request.aspx)) might throw.

So, you **need** to change your code to [`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` usage](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/05/07/scheduling-background-jobs-from-an-asp-net-application-in-net-4-5-2) and copy values from [`HttpContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx).

Other related resources:

- [The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) by Phil Haack
- [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) by Scott Hanselman
- [Calling an async method without awaiting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29580656/213550)' answer by @StephenCleary

Answer (score -1):

> Let's say the completion of the operation is not relevant to the request and it is independent of it but I want that Task to be completed for sure even if the request has closed/completed before it. Will that task be completed if we omit await keyword to call ExecuteAsynchronously

In this case it would not be guaranteed to be completed. I think the best approach would then be to run that task in a separate process. You could host it in windows service or anything else really. With that, all the request would do is notify the service that a task needs to be ran. That would allow you to ensure that task is complete and separate the concerns from the request.

Comment: Thanks for replying on each point separately. *The main question you need to answer is whether the completion of the operation is relevant to the request, if it is then it should be awaited.* Let's say the completion of the operation is not relevant to the request and it is independent of it but I want that Task to be completed for sure even if the request has closed/completed before it. Will that task be completed if we omit await keyword to call ExecuteAsynchronously

Comment: You are not calling async methods properly in Web Forms. [Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45).

Comment: @mason Good point I completely missed the web forms aspect. Made appropriate edits.